# How to upload a file on a button click in an android app?

Tags: android, file, upload

I am a newbie in android and I want to do the following in my app. I have a button in my activity and I want to load a file or an image into my app on button click. How can i do that? Any links or tutorials will be helpful.

Comment: you need to upload file into a server???

Answer (score 0):

You're gonna need to provide a bit more information like how the app is structured and where the images are (if they're stored in the apps resources or assets or you have to retrieve them from a URL), and where you intend to use the images, etc.

A good start as always to android development is the android developer documentation here:
http://developer.android.com/, as well as the Android API for reference here: https://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html

As well as stackoverflow :D

Anyway, for reacting to button 'clicks', set the button's `onClickListener` as below:

```
    yourButton.setOnClickListener (new OnClickListener () {
        @ Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            // do stuff here
        }
    });
```

Just fill in the blanks and look here https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html

Comment: My images are located in the sdcard. I want to retrieve them from the sdcard and store it in the server